# SharedPreferences mistake

Tags: android, eclipse

**SharedPreferences** mistake in android "eclipse"

I'm trying to test an application that depends on SharedPreferences storage !

I used the **SeekBar** and **EditText** and one Button ..

The EditText to write anything and the SeekBar to change the size of the text ..

Then I saved the text and its size when i pressed to the button ..

So when I run the app again ..I must find the same text and size ..

And really i found the same text but the size was bigger than one i save .. 
What is the wrong ? 
Hint : there is no errors in the code ..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private EditText editText ;
    private Button btn ;
    private SeekBar seekBar ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
       seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1) ;
       btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
       btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Test", MODE_PRIVATE)    ;
         prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)    ;
         Editor myEditor=prefs.edit();
         myEditor.putFloat("fontsize", editText.getTextSize()) ;
         myEditor.putString("text", editText.getText().toString()) ;
         myEditor.commit() ;
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;

        }

       }) ;

       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Test", MODE_PRIVATE) ;
       prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)  ;

       float fs = prefs.getFloat("fontsize", 12) ;
       seekBar.setProgress((int) fs) ;
       editText.setText(prefs.getString("text" , "") ) ;
       editText.setTextSize(seekBar.getProgress()) ;

       seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editText.setTextSize(seekBar.getProgress()) ;
        }
    }) ;

    }
```

Comment: Mind showing the code?

Comment: okkk ,, just a minute !

Comment: i think it is clearer .. :/ !!

Comment: Hint: There's no code.

Comment: can you please post you xml of EditText ?

Comment: sorry ,, there is now ,,

Comment: By default you are getting font size "12". So if you have set textsize for "10" for example then you will always get "12" because by default you are getting "12" size.

Comment: That's silly, @PG_Android. The default is only returned if the SharedPreference doesn't exist. Once he writes it, the written value is returned, not the default. That's why it's called the "default."

Comment: Yeah you'r right. But for that you have to check if it is exists or not or he can use "TypedValue" for set Text size for EditText

Comment: You don't have to check whether a preference exists -- that's exactly what the default parameter is for. If it doesn't exist, return default. If it does exist, return value. This has nothing to do with the `TypedValue` parameter *at all.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(float)).

`getTextSize()` returns the size in pixels. `setTextSize()` expects the size in scaled pixels. You'll want to use `setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, fs );`

Comment: You're weeeeellllcome! Glad I could help!

Comment: hhhhhhhhhh sorry i must say .. it is working not it is work :D !!